# Tenant Wide Drive Search

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Currently, we are looping through each `siteid` in a tenant to search for a given keyword using:

```
/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/search(q='{search-query}')
```

In our case, we have more than 500 sites under our tenant so for searching using this API we have to pass each `siteid` and process the results.

Is there a way out of this? Can we search for keywords across the whole tenant with a single API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, Microsoft Graph doesn't support searching across `site` resources like this.

For the authenticated user, you can scope the search to include any [items that can access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search#searching-for-items-a-user-can-access) via `/me/drive/search(q='{search-query}')`. This is a little different than what you're doing by iterating through `sites` so I suspect this won't give you the expected results (although you certainly can, and should, confirm that for yourself).

What you're more likely looking for is the [SharePoint Search REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview). You can use this API by issuing an `GET` to a URI that looks something like this:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'
```

In order to use this API will need an `access_token` for SharePoint however.

If you're using the v1 Endpoint this should be pretty straightforward. You'll need to update your App registration to include the SharePoint API but once that is done you can simply refresh your existing `access_token` while switching your `resource` to `https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/`. This will give you a new token with permission to call the SharePoint API.

Unfortunately, this won't work with the v2 Endpoint as the SharePoint REST API does not support these tokens today. You would, therefore, need to switch to v1 and force your user to reauthenticate which may be a bit more challenging.